# jqGrid filtering on the client-side using "filterToolbar"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have to add filtering to a jqGrid that is completely managed on the client side (data is only loaded once from the server).

I need to use filterToolbar in order to filter the grid data, but couldn't find info if there is a default search mechanism on the client side. Is a server-side search the only way to do this?

Thanks,
Cosmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately search (filtering) is only performed server-side, [according to the jqGrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config):

> Currently we do not have module for searching on local data i.e when a datatype options is set to local. All the searching is done server side.

**Update**

As noted below, support for client-side filtering has been added in jqGrid 3.7. For an example see the [Tooolbar search](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) demo under the 3.7 section.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. I guess I'll have to refactor after all.

Thanks,
Cosmin

Comment: As of version 3.7 they support it now.  It's pretty awesome.

Comment: @Justin: The Toolbar Search demo under section 3.7 draws up the search toolbar for every column. Is it possible to have just one search toolbar that filters data across all columns and all pages?

Comment: @SK11: Not as far as I know, although Oleg might be able to help. To get to the bottom of things I recommend you post this as its own question.