# jqgrid - search toolbar

Tags: jqgrid

The Toolbar Search demo under section 3.7 draws up the search toolbar for every column. Is it possible to have just one search toolbar that filters data across all columns and all pages?

For more info: [jqGrid filtering on the client-side using "filterToolbar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849086/jqgrid-filtering-on-the-client-side-using-filtertoolbar/2850607#2850607)

**JSON**

```
{
   "mypage":{
      "outerwrapper":{
         "page":"1",
         "total":"2",
         "records":"2",
         "innerwrapper":{
            "rows":[
               {
                  "id":"1",
                  "cells": [
                     {
                         "fieldType": "image",
                         "label": "image",
                         "value": "<img src=icon.gif>"                         
                     },
                     {
                         "fieldType": "number",
                         "label": "number",
                         "value": 100
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "string",
                        "label": "string",
                        "value": "James Kisnar"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "alphanumeric",
                        "label": "alphanumeric",
                        "value": "77 Wall Street"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "date",
                        "label": "date",
                        "value": "12/20/2011"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "decimal",
                        "label": "decimal",
                        "value": "23.55"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "id":"2",
                  "cells": [
                     {
                         "fieldType": "image",
                         "label": "image",
                         "value": "<img src=icon.gif>"                         
                     },
                     {
                         "fieldType": "number",
                         "label": "number",
                         "value": 140
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "string",
                        "label": "string",
                        "value": "James Kitchener"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "alphanumeric",
                        "label": "alphanumeric",
                        "value": "123 ABC"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "date",
                        "label": "date",
                        "value": "12/20/2011"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "decimal",
                        "label": "decimal",
                        "value": "23.55"
                     }
                  ]
               }, 
               {
                  "id":"3",
                  "cells": [
                     {
                         "fieldType": "image",
                         "label": "image",
                         "value": "<img src=icon.gif>"                         
                     },
                     {
                         "fieldType": "number",
                         "label": "number",
                         "value": 657
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "string",
                        "label": "string",
                        "value": "Loo Gatner"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "alphanumeric",
                        "label": "alphanumeric",
                        "value": "123 XYZ"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "date",
                        "label": "date",
                        "value": "12/20/2011"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "decimal",
                        "label": "decimal",
                        "value": "23.55"
                     }
                  ]
               }, 
               {
                  "id":"4",
                  "cells": [
                     {
                         "fieldType": "image",
                         "label": "image",
                         "value": "<img src=icon.gif>"                         
                     },
                     {
                         "fieldType": "number",
                         "label": "number",
                         "value": 1290
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "string",
                        "label": "string",
                        "value": "William Parker"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "alphanumeric",
                        "label": "alphanumeric",
                        "value": "123 FGH"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "date",
                        "label": "date",
                        "value": "12/20/2011"
                     },
                     {
                        "fieldType": "decimal",
                        "label": "decimal",
                        "value": "23.55"
                     }
                  ]
               } 
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**JQGrid Definition**

```
$(function (){
    var getValueByName = function (cells, cellItem) {
        var i, count = cells.length, item;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
            item = cells[i];
            if (item.label === cellItem) {
                return item.value;
            }
        }
        return '';
    };
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
        url: "jqgrid.json",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8",
        colNames:['Image','Number', 'String', 'Alphanumeric','Date','Decimal'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'image',index:'image',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "image");}, width:150, align:"center"},
            {name:'number',index:'number',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "number");}, width:150, align:"left", sortable:true},
            {name:'string',index:'string',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "string");}, width:150, align:"left", sortable:true},
            {name:'alphanumeric',index:'alphanumeric',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "alphanumeric");}, width:200, align:"left", sortable:true},
            {name:'date',index:'date',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "date");}, width:150,align:"left", sortable:true},
            {name:'decimal',index:'decimal',jsonmap:function(obj){return getValueByName(obj.cells, "decimal");}, width:150,align:"left", sortable:true},
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            root: "mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows",          
            page: "mypage.outerwrapper.page",
            total: "mypage.outerwrapper.total",
            records: "mypage.outerwrapper.records",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        rowNum:2,
        rowList:[2, 4],
        pager: '#Pager',
        recordpos: 'left',
        multiboxonly:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        multiselect: true,
        scrolloffset: 0,    
        loadonce: true,     
        sortable: true, 
        sorttype: "text",
        cache: true,
        height: "120px"
    });
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager',{add:false,del:false,edit:false,position:'right'});
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
});
```

Comment: Do you have grid with the columns having the same type? Do you want for example to have only one input field and want to filter for the text in any column?

Comment: I have updated the post with **JSON** and **JQGrid Definition**. Yes, I want only 1 input field and want to filter for the search criteria in any column and any page.

Comment: **In firefox** - I don't see the search toolbar, **In IE** - the search toolbar is hidden and I have to use the scroll bar on the right to navigate to it.

Comment: @Oleg: I was hoping to get some help from you on this one.